# Help finding the formula for this sequence {$23$, $114$, $187$, $473$, $2792$, $5624$, $19640$, $75884$, $187211$, $479798$, $1452835$, $5102237$...}

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

Excuse the large title (The 'good title' page said not to be afraid to make it too long)

$\{23,114,187,473,2792,5624,19640,75884,187211,479797,1452795,5102858,14872865,72392867,146262888\}$

I'm trying to figure out the nth term for these numbers. To help:

- I'm generating these numbers on a python program:

  ```
  import math
  n=23
  digit=0
  while(True):
      pi=n*math.sin(math.radians(((90*n)-180)/(n)))*math.sin(math.radians(180/n))
      strpi=str(pi)
      count1=2
      while(count1<len(strpi)-1):
          if(strpi[count1]==str(math.pi)[count1]):
              if(digit<count1):
                  print(n,"\n\n",pi,"\n")
                  digit=count1
          else:
              break
          count1+=1
      n+=1
  ```
- For the non-programmers the program uses this formula:

  $ π=n \cdot \sin(\frac{90n-180}{n}) \cdot \sin(\frac{180}{n})$

  What this does is calculate $\pi$ more accurately the higher the value of $n$. The program 
  recorded the value of $n$ each time the next decimal value of $\pi$ was found (increasing $n$ by $1$ starting from $0$ each time). So if $n$ is $23$ the 
  output is $3.1$  and if it is $114$ the value is is $3.14$. Note that these values have 
  decimal places after them that are not digits of $\pi$. And this is in degrees, not radians.
- This formula is derived from this one (Done with the sine rule):

  $ A=nr^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{90n-180}{n}) \cdot \sin(\frac{180}{n})$

  $A=$ The area of a proper polygon, $r=$ length from centre to corner, $n=$ number of sides

I substituted $A$ with $πr^2$ and simplified

- It took me a while to realise that the difference between the first two values is larger than the difference between the second and third ($91$ then $73$)
- If my program gets a new value I'll be adding it in. And if you want me to create an algorithm to find different data relating to this to help you solve it, or have an improved program do not hesitate to ask/suggest.
- Technically speaking, the first element could be labelled as $12$ which gives the first *digit* as $3$.
- Below are the pi values given when n is increased

[image]

- Here is a GIF showing the increase of numbers as $n$ increases
  [image]

Comment: In radians and after simplification, you compute $\frac n2\sin \frac{2\pi}{n}$. It's half the perimeter of a polygon with $n/2$ sides.

Comment: This is in degrees. I'll add this in

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I highly doubt you're going to find a formula for this.

Comment: Of course it's in degrees, that's why I translated this to radians. Degrees are useless when you want to use some calculus, and with calculus you get pretty easily that $\frac n2 \sin \frac{2\pi}{n}\to\pi$ as $n\to\infty$, albeit very slowly. That's basically the method used by Archimedes to get his approximation $\frac{22}7$. You could find an asymptotic approximation for your integer sequence, but like @MattSamuel I don't think there is a simple closed form.

Comment: A pi on both sides of the equation?

$π=\frac{n}{2} × sin(\frac{2π}{n})$

Comment: I've edited the equation to show how I derived it

Comment: Yes, a $\pi$ on both sides, but note this is *not* an equality. You *approximate* the circle by a regular polygon. When the number of sides get larger, the approximation gets better, but it's never an equality. Side note: your derivation is correct, but you get the same by approximating the perimeter with $n/2$ sides, and it was my first guess.

Comment: So if I was to substitute 2(pi) on the first side with 2(3.14), then substituted my answer back into the equation indefinitely as I increase the value of n. Do I produce new digits of pi?

Comment: Now may be a bad time, but I haven't even learnt calculus yet...

Comment: I made this formula to avoid using sigma

Comment: Are you looking for $\pi$ or just interested in sequences? There is an [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) I found reading the book "Alex in Numberland". It did not have your sequence but I hear it contains tens of thousands of them and even an 8 minute graphic video of the first thousand that you might find amusing.

Comment: What is \p- I'm quite inexperienced with mathsJAX

Comment: @poetasis Funnily enough it's neither. I'm interested in infinities. I've been trying to play around with defining infinity as the number of digits in an irrational number or a recurring decimal with symbol ∞. I also figured that I would allow for it to be divided by a number such as $\frac{∞}{3}$. Both values would be infinite but the latter would be three times larger. So, assuming this to be true, if I was to substitute $n$ with ∞ in my equation I would only get a *third* of the digits of pi. If the nth term for the digit was f(n)=? then I could substitute f(∞) to find *all* of the digits.

Comment: Also remember that the numbers in the sequence will be different for other (non decimal) bases

Comment: @yolo You have a lot to explore with $\infty$. It's not a number in the sense that dividing or multiplying can result in one smaller or bigger than the other. There $are$ different sizes having nothing to do with arithmetic. Also, there are many slower and faster formulae for finding $\pi$. They are a full-time study in themselves.  Good luck in your explorations; they will be both torturous and fun.

Comment: @poetasis It gets stranger. I thought of $0. \overline{0}1$ at first actually. When multiplying it by $10^\infty$ as per my definition you get 1. Note I'm not *adding* 1 at the end  of the infinite 0s. Instead it is the last digit of the sequence. So If I was to write $0. \overline{0}15$ the number of place values stays the same so you get 0.000...001 and 0.000...015. This may seem infinitesimal but you could write $\frac{0.5}{10^\infty}$ which simply cannot be expressed as a number. This does come at a consequence- ordinary recurring decimals turn irrational and their fractions the opposite.

Comment: @poetasis The reason this is true is because of $0.\overline{9}$ no longer being equal to 1. If we assume that my idea is true, we assume that recurring decimals, although infinite, have a fixed place value therefore when multiplying $0.\overline{9}$ by 10 we get $9.\overline{9}0$ and when doing vertical subtraction we get an infinite case of borrowing from the 9 to the left and at the end of that subtraction we get $8.\overline{8}1$ instead of 9. $3.\overline{3} * 3=9.\overline{9}. This concept may be difficult to grasp. Imagine a recurring decimal  on an infinite strip of paper. You hold...

Comment: @poetasis both ends of the paper are in your hand. I you can change the values of both ends but as you keep on going along the paper you will never see the two ends meet because they go on infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jean-Claude Arbaut says, you are approximating $\pi$ with $\frac n2\sin \frac {2\pi}n$.  For $n$ large the argument of $\sin$ is small and we can use the Taylor series.  You are then computing $\pi-\frac n{12}\left(\frac {2\pi}n\right)^3+O(\frac 1{n^4})$  The alternating series theorem says that the error of truncation is of the same sign as the first ignored term and smaller than it.  You are looking for the times when the error gets smaller than the digits of $\pi$ starting somewhere.  For your first example, you need the error to be less than $0.04159265\ldots$.  The small gap between $114$ and $187$ comes because that digit of $\pi$ is $1$.  I am sure there is no easy way to compute the exact terms because they depend on the remainder after some number of digits, which can vary over a wide range.  We can ask when $\frac n{12}\left(\frac {2\pi}n\right)^3 \lt 10^{-k}$, which comes when $n\gt \left(\frac{12\cdot 10^k}{8\pi^3}\right)^{1/3}$ and we would expect terms to be roughly multiplied by $\sqrt {10} \approx 3.162$

Added:  I plotted $n$, the number of correct decimals, vs $\log_{10}a(n)$ where $a(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ term from the sequence above.  It forms a reasonable straight line with formula $\log_{10}a(n)\approx 0.9225+0.4806n$.  I suspect with more terms in the sequence it would converge on $\log_{10}a(n)=1+\frac n2$  A plot is below
[image]

Comment: Are you saying the pattern is roughly $n^3* root 10$?

Comment: I plotted the number of decimals against the base $10$ log of the numbers in your series.  The fit came out $0.9226+0.4806n$, so it goes up close to $\sqrt {10}$ each time (the coefficient would be $0.5$).  It is about $10^{1+\frac n2}$

Comment: Can you get any closer?

Comment: I am sure with much more data the formula would converge on exactly what I gave.  As I said, there is a fair amount of noise in the data because the remaining digits can vary so much.

Comment: probably shoulda mentioned this in the OP in the first place: but there seems to be some sort of pattern each time $n$ increases. Look at the pi values. They seem to have 5 extra 0s after diverging from pi. I'll post it.

Comment: @yolo:  that is to be expected.  The calculation is converging on $\pi$ from below as my formula shows.  The first time that $n$ digits are correct will be when the calculation crosses over the number that is $\pi$ truncated to $n$ digits, so we expect a series of zeros.  I suspect the number of zeros will increase as we go along.

Comment: I added a GIF if that helps. Unlike something like the monte carlo method, as soon as a digit of pi is reached, it locks in and doesn't change. Also, what 'more data' do you need?

Comment: More data would just be extending the series with many more terms.  I don't think a few more would do much, but ten times more terms might get the coefficients closer.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87154/discussion-between-yolo-and-ross-millikan).